# How to inject services into RouteInitializerFn (new routing DSL)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm switching my app over to the new routing DSL.  Specifically, I want to do something like this with `preEnter`:

```dart
final RouteInitializerFn routes =(Router router, ViewFactory views) {
  views.configure({
   'chat': ngRoute(
     path: '/chat',
     // authService.requireState returns a Future<bool>, and may invoke an HttpRequest
     preEnter: (RoutePreEnterEvent e) => e.allowEnter(authService.requireState(LOGGED_IN)),
     view: 'views/chat.html'),

   'login': ngRoute(
     path: '',
     defaultRoute: true,
     view: 'views/login.html')
  });
}
```

This would be configured in the module as follows:

`value(RouteInitializerFn, routes);`

In case you missed it, I'm referencing an injectable `authService` within the `RouteInitializerFn`.  This isn't possible since `RouteInitializerFn` is a function and not a class, so nothing can be injected into it.  If I encapsulated the `routes` function within a class, I'm not sure how I could configure `RouteInitializerFn`, so I'm in a bit of a quandary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a pretty cool solution to this problem.  Turns out, if you define a `call` method on a class that satisfies a typedef, you can configure it as an implementation of the typedef.  *Very* cool. Here is my solution:

```dart
class Routes
{
  final UserService _userService;

  Routes(this._userService);

  void call(Router router, ViewFactory views) 
  {
    views.configure({
      'chat': ngRoute(
          path: '/chat',
          preEnter: (RoutePreEnterEvent e) => e.allowEnter(this._userService.requireUserState(UserService.LOGGED_IN)),
          view: 'views/chat.html'
      ),

      'login': ngRoute(
          path: '',
          defaultRoute: true,
          view: 'views/login.html'
      )
    });
  }
}
```

and this is how it's configured within the module:

```dart
// old syntax
type(RouteInitializerFn, implementedBy: Routes);

// new syntax
bind(RouteInitializerFn, toImplementation: Routes);
```

Comment: This neat solution seems to have broken with Dart 1.5. I'm now getting "Illegal argument(s): No type factory provided for Routes! (resolving RouteInitializerFn)"

Comment: I'm also on 1.5.1. No code was changed and dependencies are exactly the version they were prior upgrading dart.

Comment: Removing this from pubspec.yaml "fixes" it:

transformers:
- angular

Comment: Annotating the class with @Injectable() fixes the problem when using the transformer under dart-1.5.